# How do I retrieve cumulative views using the YouTube APIs?

Tags: youtube-api

I can't find anything on the web or the API docs for how to retrieve the very simple graph that shows up when you check the stats of a YouTube video right on the video page; that is, when you click the "Video Statistics" button to the right of the View Count on a video.

I just want a graph that starts at 0 views when the video was first uploaded to the number of views now; it should increase cumulatively with time. Anyone know how to get this?

Note -- I don't want data broken down per day (I'm aware of the new Analytics API).

Answer (score 0):

The newly public YouTube Analytics API should allow you to get that sort of data (views broken down by day over a period of time).

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/

Comment: I wanted cumulative data, not broken down per day.

Comment: You can keep a running total of the view counts from the previous days and add it to the view count for a given day to get the cumulative view count. That's how you'd have to do it.